# Accidently did system-wide install of flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I accidentally did a system-wide install of flask and sqlalchemy.  I "sudo pip install"ed both of them, and now I'm wondering how i can uninstall both of those off my system.  I already have virtualenv all set up, so I don't want flask or sqlalchemy attached to my system.  I read that having it directly installed can cause problems when working with different frameworks and different versions of a framework.

Is it a problem that I did a system-wide install of these packages?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sudo pip uninstall flask` should do the trick.  And yes, having it installed globally can cause issues if you're working with different versions of other packages.