# How to reverse system-wide installation of Flask

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, uninstallation

So I created a virtual environment but forgot to activate it.  I then ran `pip install flask` thinking I was in the new virtualenv.  This returned a denied permissions error, so I ran it again with `sudo` in front.  Shortly after, I realized what I had done.  I did a quick search here and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874113/accidently-did-system-wide-install-of-flask-and-sqlalchemy).  However, when I run `sudo pip uninstall flask` (as suggested in that link) I get this back "Can't uninstall 'Flask'. No files were found to uninstall."

Did I actually install it system-wide? If so, why does it tell me this when I try to uninstall it, and how do I actually reverse this system-wide installation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked that the initial installation actually was successful ? Can you open python interpreter and type "import flask"

Comment: If `flask` isn't exactly the right name for the package, `pip install` does a lot more guessing than `pip uninstall` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pretty weird that you can't uninstall using pip... However, you can always resort to a manual removal if necessary:

- Go to your python install `sites-packages` directory. If you don't know where that is, an easy way is to run the following:

  ```
  >>> import flask
  >>> flask.__file__
  ```
- Remove the `flask` directory in there, and the `Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg-info` that may exist

Comment: within my python2.7 directory I have site-packages/ and dist-packages/ but site-packages/ is empty.  dist-packages/ on the other hand has both directories you referred to.  Is it safe to remove them from here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this directory layout. Was does `flask.__file__` tells you? Is it from here that is was imported?

Comment: Oh, apparently, [`dist-packages` is just a Debian specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages), so you're safe to remove flask from it.

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages which makes it look like they are the same kind of directory but Ubuntu (which I am running) installs to dist- instead of sites-